# SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient() VERY slow with uncached CRL

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, ssl

A server I connect to has recently changed it's SSL certificate. Since the change, **SSL authentication is taking in excess of ten seconds to complete when the Certificate Revocation List is downloaded.**

I'm using the *RemoteCertificateChainCallback* to validate the certificate, however the delay occurs BEFORE the callback is called, so it's not the building of the cert chain or any other action there that's causing the delay

The issue only occurs when the CRL is NOT CACHED, i.e. I need to delete the CRL cache (Documents&settings/[user]AppData/Microsoft/CertificateUrlCache *or something similar*) to repro it more than once on a single day.

If I disable CRL checking in the AuthenticateAsClient() call, the authentication is quick.

Using a network sniffer, I can see that *when* the CRL is eventually requested, it downloads almost instantaneously, so the delay is not a network latency one (at least not to the CRL server).

One odd thing that I see with the network sniffer is that after the initial SSL certificate retrieval from the server, there is a five second delay until the CRL is downloaded.**

Has anyone got any suggestions as to what may be going on during this stage, and what the delay may be caused by?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** OK, I've used reflector and a memory profiler to delve into. AuthenticateAsClient. It looks like **most of the time is spent building the certificate chain**, i.e.:

```
if (!CAPISafe.CertGetCertificateChain(hChainEngine, pCertContext, ref pTime, invalidHandle, ref cert_chain_para, dwFlags, IntPtr.Zero, ref ppChainContext))
```

If I don't request CRL validation, then this returns almost instantaneously, with CRL-checking enabled, about 4 seconds.

I suspect I'll see the same delay if I manually attempt to build the chain in my RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.

This wouldn't really be a problem if the CRL was cached, however it seems like this caching is not working on a Windows7 customer. *Why*?? Well I guess that's the next task...

Could anyone explain what could be causing the chain-building to take so long?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that here is an answer for this question:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2011/09/27/big-delay-when-calling-sslstream-authenticateasclient/

> Digging a bit further to understand why CertGetCertificateChain took
>   so long, I saw that we were trying to download the following file from
>   the Internet:
>
> http://www.download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootstl.cab
>
> Why were we downloading this file? Well, this will happen by default
>   on Windows when we build the chain of a cert which root CA cert is not
>   installed in the system. This is called the Automatic Root
>   Certificates Update feature, and it is available on Windows XP/Server
>   2003 and later OS versions, including Windows 7/Server 2008 R2.